# Are process VSZ memory details visible anywhere in GKE/Stackdriver?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, stackdriver

When logged in to a container, top/ps allows us to see VSZ memory statistics for one or more processes. I can not seem to find this same information in stackdriver. Is it available anywhere, or do we need to setup our own Prometheus instance and export process_virtual_memory_bytes data ourselves?

Stackdriver has this metric under the "anthos" namespace, but it does not appear to have any data for our GKE cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus metrics are collected using an in-cluster agents in GKE and sent into Stackdriver. You can check these metrics (including `process_virtual_memory_bytes`) using [Stackdriver Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/).

For that, yo can go to the [Metrics Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-explorer) and use either `GKE Container` or `Kubernetes Container` as *Resource type*. The *Metric* field should contain the specific Prometheus gauge that you're looking for.

Finally, consider that this assumes that Stackdriver Monitoring is enabled in the cluster.